# How to connect the output of a bash command to cat?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to connect the output of a `"find"` command to a `"cat"` command:

`find -size 8c`
returns `./test.txt` (it's my only file with a size of 8 bytes in this folder)

`cat ./test.txt`
returns `iamatest` (The content of `test.txt`)

But when I try to connect the two:
`find -size 8c | cat`
It returns `./test.txt` the name of the file and not it's content. I must be missing something: I want find to pass it's output as an input to cat.

I also tried `cat <(find -size 8c)` but it also returns the name of the file instead of the content.

Comment: Passing information to a command (like `cat`) as arguments and via stdin are quite different; see [my answer here](https://superuser.com/questions/600253/why-is-xargs-necessary/600273#600273).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can call `cat` on the `find` command's output:

```
cat $(find -size 8c)
```

This gets turned into

```
cat test.txt
```

(assuming that's the only result)

Comment: This will get confused if the filename(s) contain whitespace and/or wildcards (both of which are totally legal). `find`'s `-exec` option (see l'L'l's answer)is much more reliable.

Comment: @GordonDavisson is correct - this was specifically for the case of `test.txt`. See I'L'I's answer for the right approach.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `-exec` option of `find`:

```
find . -size 8c -exec cat {} \;
```

If you want to limit the depth use:

```
find . -size 8c -maxdepth 1 -exec cat {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

### What is wrong with your solution?

You got `./test.txt` as an output for `find -size 8c | cat` because `cat` without parameters is alias for `cat /dev/stdin`. It means `cat` just prints whatever it got as standard input.

### One way to solve it

One possible solution for your problem is to use `xargs` command. It gives you an option to pass standard output of one command as command line argument(s) of another one.

Since this definition is pretty general, let me explain it on your example.

```
find -size 8c | xargs cat
```

will output:

```
iamatest
```

What `xargs` did here?

It passed standard output of `find -size 8c` which is `./test.txt` as command line argument of `cat` making it exactly the same as `cat ./test.txt`.

### If you have more than one 8 byte file

If you had another file `test_2.txt` with `12345678` as content `find -size 8c` will give you:

```
./test.txt
./test_2.txt
```

Calling `find -size 8c | xargs cat` will give you:

```
iamatest12345678
```

Which is exactly the same as if you run `cat ./test.txt ./test_2.txt`